# Issue with Orientation in iphone/iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, orientation

I am having an app which is in Landscape Mode.

The app is designed both for iPhone and iPad.

I am opening Photo Library to access photos from there and also capturing photos from some of my views.

But as of I know, Photo library can only be opened in Portrait Mode, So I select all the orientation from the setting shown below.

[image]

I have done the same thing for iPad also.

So I tried this code from all the view.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight ;
}
```

So that all the views can be locked in portrait mode only.

But my views still shows in portrait mode also.

For Photo Library, I made a different class like below.

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController8 : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ;
}

@end



@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController2 : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController2

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

So my photo library is showing in portrait mode but my all other views shows in Portrait Mode.

So How can I solve this issue?

Please help me.

Stuck on this for quite a while.

Thanks in advance....

```
**Edited**
```

[image]

If I do like this my app shows fully in Landscape mode but it crashes when I try to open photo library.

How Can I do this?

Please help....

Comment: So my photo library is showing in POTRAIT mode but my all other views shows in POTRAIT Mode. What do you mean? Typo? If you can, upload a sample project to Github and link here, someone can fix that for you.

Comment: If i don't select portrait from my settings of my project like shown in the image then my app will crash because photo library can only be opened in portrait mode for iPhone...

Comment: self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); use in your photo library view

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this situation , and i found solution , see my code below.

First comment all orientation methods that you have written in every class.

then check mark all orientaition like below

[image]

now in AppDelegate.m file write below code in which "**presented**" is UIViewController in which you are trying to open pickerview

```
  - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    if (self.window.rootViewController) {
        UIViewController* presented = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        if([presented isKindOfClass:[PhotoVC class]])
        {
           orientations = [presented supportedInterfaceOrientations];
           return orientations;
       }
       orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
   return orientations;
}
```

Now  replace code in your  `NonRotatingUIImagePickerController2` with my code like below

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController2 : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController2

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}


@end
```

Please check it and let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Problem because of NavigationController?

Comment: No problem is not because of NavigationController, you are missing something my friend, have you removed all orientation code from all view controllers ?

Comment: Yes I did but I found the another solution https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController/tree/master/Classes/ELCImagePicker which opens ImagePicker in Landscape Mode. Thanks so much for your help till now. I'll keep your code and use it for future projects because right now I am making changes to an old project so problem is because of that as I don't have much idea about the previous developer's code. I am just making some modificatiosns to existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open your storyboard, select the view controllers, then choose "Landscape" in Orientation dropdown:

See this picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnnh8auzuyb2waw/Screenshot%202014-05-06%2013.24.02.png